# Set cookie to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById("ajazload"), 1, false)
});
</scr‌​ipt>
```

And I'd like to add to this function a cookie, in order to prevent it to reload a second time when the user reloads the page.

May you have an idea to do that ?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Working with cookies in jQuery is very simple if you use something like the [`jQuery.cookie` plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Example code:

```
if(!$.cookie('mediaplayer')) {
    YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById("ajazload"), 1, false);
    $.cookie('mediaplayer',1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys for this solution, Cookies with jQuery will help me in my projects.

However, I realize that my idea was wrong, because now the Yahoo Media Player doesn't recognize any songs after the second visit of the page, and doesn't provide the precedent tracks that it parsed at the first visit of the page.

I thought that the player would save the precedent tracks, and stop to add duplicate tracks when users are visiting the site, but it's not the case: it provides either zero or duplicate tracks indefinitely... So I'm in impasse now...

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery Cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie('site_reloaded', 'true');
```

Then before you reload the page:

```
if ($.cookie('site_reloaded') != 'true') { ... }
```